# Drilldown more than 1 subreport using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using the latest version of Highcharts which is Highcharts 3.0.9 And I need to do multiple level of drilldown. The example provided only showing 1 level of drilldown only.

The sample code:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }, {
            name: 'Fruits',
            y: 2,
            drilldown: 'fruits'
        }, {
            name: 'Cars',
            y: 4,
            drilldown: 'cars'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            data: [
                ['Cats', 4],
                ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'fruits',
            data: [
                ['Apples', 4],
                ['Oranges', 2]
            ]
        }, {
            id: 'cars',
            data: [
                ['Toyota', 4],
                ['Opel', 2],
                ['Volkswagen', 2]
            ]
        }]
    }
})
```

The link of the code : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dP35L/)

So how to do multiple level of drilldown using the new version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done it well Hayu Rahiza.

All you need to do is repeat the same you did in series section in the drill down section also

```
    {
        name: 'Toyota',
        y: 4,
        drilldown: 'Toyota'
    },{
        id: 'Toyota',
        data: [
            ['Corolla', 4],
            ['Fortuner', 2],
            ['Etios', 2],
            ['Liva', 10]
        ]
    }
```

I've update your fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/dP35L/1/

I Hope this will help you

Comment: Yay.. Thanks a lot strikers.